# VBA macro to return the difference between first and last edited dates of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I do a lot of follow up work that requires to extract some KPIs. One of these is the Process Adherence. It is basically the subtraction of two dates, these being the date a process is planned to end minus the date the process actually ended.

In excel, I have a worksheet I input the date of every process a part is subject to (See below)

[image]

We can assume the first date inputed is the planned one and all dates after this are the reschedules of said process.

I managed to make a VBA code to store all modifications of a cell in a note, but now I need a code that can take the first date stored in the note and the current value of the cell, subtract it and give me the result of this operation in Sheet 2.

[image]

Can anyone help me to achieve what I'm after? Thanks

***The code I have for storing all modifications of a cell as a note.***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With Target
If Target.Column <> 13 Then Exit Sub
If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
Dim strNewText$, strCommentOld$, strCommentNew$
strNewText = .Text
If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
strCommentOld = .Comment.Text & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
Else
strCommentOld = ""
End If
On Error Resume Next
.Comment.Delete
Err.Clear
.AddComment
.Comment.Visible = False
.Comment.Text Text:=strCommentOld & _
Format(VBA.Now, "MM/DD/YYYY at h:MM AM/PM") & " - " & Application.UserName & Chr(10) & strNewText
.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `give me the result of this operation in Sheet 2` Please share the layout of Sheet2.  [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have you tried reading the comment text, splitting on vbLF and then looping over the resulting array of lines to extract the dates?

Comment: @taller The sheet 2 is just an empty sheet, I just mentioned because the code need to search for the input in one sheet and give the result in another sheet

Comment: @timwilliams I'm not a very proficient VBA user, I get by getting examples that are close to what I need and modify them, could you please share an example of what you just described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example as a user-defined function:

```
Function FirstDateEntered(c As Range)
    Dim txt, arr, el, dt
    If Not c.Comment Is Nothing Then 'cell has comment?
        txt = c.Comment.Text
        arr = Split(txt, vbLf)  'split text to lines
        For Each el In arr      'loop resulting array
            If IsDate(el) Then
                FirstDateEntered = DateValue(el)
                Exit Function 'done checking
            End If
        Next el
    End If
    FirstDateEntered = ""
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetCmt()
    Dim sSht As Worksheet, dSht As Worksheet, c As Range
    Dim sDate As String, iR As Long, lastRow As Long
    Const COL = 13 ' modify as needed
    Const START_ROW = 2 ' First data cell in COL
    Set sSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
    Set dSht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    dSht.Cells.Clear
    ' Write header row
    dSht.Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Row#", "Difference")
    iR = 1
    lastRow = sSht.Cells(sSht.Rows.Count, COL).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow >= START_ROW Then
        For Each c In sSht.Range(sSht.Cells(START_ROW, COL), sSht.Cells(lastRow, COL))
            If Not c.Comment Is Nothing Then
                sDate = Split(c.Comment.Text)(0)
                If IsDate(sDate) Then
                    iR = iR + 1
                    dSht.Cells(iR, 1) = c.Row
                    dSht.Cells(iR, 2) = CDate(c.Value) - CDate(sDate)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```